# Exceptions generating when using a gogo custom command

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, gogo-shell

I have created a felix gogo custom command using information from the bndtoools tutorial (http://bndtools.org/tutorial.html#write-a-command-component).

The code used is below:

```
@Component(properties = {
    CommandProcessor.COMMAND_SCOPE + ":String=texter",
    CommandProcessor.COMMAND_FUNCTION + ":String=text"
 },
 provide = Object.class
)
public class SocketUser
{
    private ActualUser aUser = new ActualUser();

    public SocketUser()
    {
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void text(String aMessage)
   {
       aUser.textClients(aMessage);
    }

}
```

Note that the ActualUser class has a method called textClient() which, for now, just prints out a message.

I set the appropriate things in the build and run bnd files, including the Bnd Annotations declarative services. I also have all the necessary Gogo bundles in the runtime.

Doing a "help" causes a list of commands to display, which includes the following:

```
felix:bundlelevel
felix:cd
felix:frameworklevel
felix:headers
felix:help
   .
   .
   .
scr:list
texter:text
```

where "texter:text" is my added command.

All seems well, except that when I try to use the text command I get the following failure messages:

```
g! text hello!
gogo: InvocationTargetException: null
g! text
gogo: IllegalArgumentException: Cannot coerce text() to any of [(String)]
g!
```

I think I understand the second failure message: the command needs a string in order to work. I do not understand the first failure, though.

Does anyone know why this command is not working? What is causing these InvocationTargetExceptions?

More importantly, how can I make them go away?

Someone please advise...

Answer (score 1):

I just had this error because the version of the org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime bundle calculated to be in my Run Bundles was not good.  It was 0.11.0 when I had the error.

[image]

I removed the bundle and clicked "resolve" again.  It found another version of the bundle 0.14.0 as you see in the Figure, and it works well now.